# How to point an Apple TV to an iTunes Library on a NAS?

Tags: itunes, appletv, macos, nas, storage

I have my Apple TV linked to my iTunes library stored on a network storage device by linking to my laptop. I would like to point my Apple TV directly to the iTunes library on the storage device without linking through the laptop. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you have an Apple TV 2…) You can't do it without jailbreaking.

Once you do that, you just need to run [Plex](http://forums.plexapp.com/index.php/topic/22879-plex-client-for-appletv-gen2-version-067-now-available/) or [XBMC](http://xbmc.org). I only have experience with the former, but we're very happy with the results.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with a standard AppleTV.  It may be possible with a jailbroken Apple TV or if you put something like [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) onto it.